# My computer won't boot from USB stick

Tags: linux, windows, boot, usb, arch-linux

So, here's some context. I want to switch to Linux so I've been trying some distros. The last one I tried to install was Arch. I watched a 50 minutes video of how to install it. After all, when I rebooted, GRUB didn't work. I was tired and gave up, went back to install Fedora since I like it the most but when I tried to boot with my pendrive, my pc made a "beep" and got stuck in a blank screen.

What I did after Arch failure:

- Booted up with windows boot manager
- It took 6 minutes to boot, there was some kind of error.
- First it was stuck at the ASUS logo with the spinning dots at the bottom.  Mouse turned off. HDD led turned off. A minute passes and it starts fixing  something, then it boots up.
- I deleted the partitions that I used to install Arch as I always do.
- Restart the pc just to make sure it wouldn't happen again, but it happens. It takes long to boot and now my audio is not working. For some reason it just stopped.

I am downloading Windows 10 iso but I'm not sure if I'll be able to install it since my pc won't boot from usb.

edit: I don't know exactly what error, it just started scanning the hard drive.

What could be the problem?

Comment: "there was some kind of error." - Please give us the exact error you received by editing your quesiton.

Comment: Recovery options in Windows 10 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options This Support page will show you how to do many things with Windows Recovery Options including Resetting The PC to Factory Settings

Comment: It could also be useful to state the PC/motherboard brand/model.

Answer (score -1):

It would be helpful to know what kind is the model of your motherboard, but usually I would check it two things:

1. make sure that USB stick boots on different computer
2. make sure that the PC is booting in UEFI compatibility mode. It should be pretty straightforward in your BIOS settings

Those pretty long times that you describe tell me that something is wrong with your hardware, so I would try to see it the HDD is not corrupted and that there is no corrosion on your memory DIMMs.

good luck

Answer (score -1):

I'm new here, but now noticed that this post was over a year old, still It were apparently high up on the list. Did someone upvote it? If not, it could be good to lock this thread.

To follow up on some of Ilyas points.
You can use https://www.memtest86.com/ for checking memory/ram, it's a very lengthy test, just run the defaults. Ram can work while still being bad, until they finally breaks down, so sometimes you can boot several times with issues until it's no longer possible (most common with ram clock speed wrongly configured). Memory when broken, could allow you to use it up to a certain amount of ram or stick. Ram-sticks inserted wrongly in ports or different kinds of rams in uneven slot or missing slot in the queue, the motherboard manual will explain which slots is first in the queue.

Crystaldiskinfo will allow you to check the drive for errors, such as reallocated/corrupted sectors or spin-up issues.
https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/

It could also be that if it's Windows you manage to boot in to, that some sectors data have been corrupted, not always visible as damaged sectors or corruption or issues having, as your computer is always fixing something, it could be that data is placed continuously on bad sectors (common with old HDD, or SSDs that're either dying or just cheap).

A corrupted MBR/GPT partion can create a lot of issues as well, best would be to check the disk in another computer and if nothing is on it, the clean the disk so it's like "new" before plugging in installation media, remember to unplug any other disc, as windows would love to put boot files on other discs, boot files are placed on one disk while start files are on another. If you already had another OS installed on one of the discs, then this might be what you OS is fixing at the bootup (usually it stops booting completely, asking for the MBR/GPT disc), like a Windows troubleshooting windows that you can click on.

Other than that, it could be chkdsk which is trying to fix corruption and similar things, this scan often be repeated until you fully fix what's broken, which it doesn't always succeed on its own with.

You mentioned Windows, but that you were going to download a Windows 10 ISO, could it be that you're on a Windows 7 computer? If you have a bad unit, such as harddrive in the computer, then anything can go slow. Also when troubleshooting, always unplug what isn't necessary at least once to check if you have any broken hardware.

If it were to be an power issue, most commonly the computers will just shut down, so I won't dig deeper on that subject.

Regarding UEFI/EFI compatibility and such things, when creating a bootable usb drive, the software will take settings from your current computer and if they don't match the other computer (unless it's the same), then you won't see the pen-drive. 32/64 bit might also make a difference in this regard, if it's a very old computer, otherwise you like have everything in 64bit.

I have two computers, both with boot issues which improves over the years.
However on one I had to have a specific boot manager, which your boot manager might be when you say Windows Boot Manager. This could be a third-party boot manager, which you have to succeed to call with the right button at bootup.

In the UEFI/EFI/BIOS settings, you should make sure that you see the pendrives, which you often can select as the highest boot order and put the pendrive first. Some motherboards have special settings for boot policies, so check everything you can and see if you find something that's strange.

To troubleshoot your sound, you need to first find your sound unit in the device manager and verify that it's there and installed without issues, other than that, it could be as simple as wrong sound unit was selected.

Lastly.
If you re-installed Windows and notice that some things doesn't work, it could be that you need specific drivers from your motherboard manufactures, based on that that they have software/drivers for the OS you have succeeded to install? Sometimes you must also update your motherboard, if it haven't been done for long (especially in old computers.).